# VS2013/Cordova - Cannot debug in device even when build/deploy success due to adb

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013, apache-cordova

This problem has been bothering me for days now.
Previously, I was able to debug my Cordova App on my Android device (version 5.1.1, Lollipop).
Now, I cannot debug my app as a popup displays indicating:

> "Unable to start program
>   %APPDATA%\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe"

I have confirmed that this program is located at the correct folder.

**What I have tried:**

1) According to my research, using an updated software for Android will make this popup "go away".
However, I am already using a device on Lollipop version and he problem still exists. In fact, it is the same device that I use previously.

2) I have also read that I should delete a folder then re-build my app. I lost the link to the folder or the reference but I remember it being a componentmodule or componentcache which is being regenerated after a build.

**Notes:**

0) Even a blank app (new Cordova project) displays this problematic popup.

1) There are no Build and Deploy problems or errors encountered.

2) There is no problem in debugging using Ripple. I encounter this problem when I try to debug on my device or the emulator.

3) Visual Studio seems to be opening the app in an emulator instead of my device. Output log indicates

> Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
>   "C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js"
>   --platform android --path "D:_My Files\Test Dummy Path\POTATOMIDGETS\POTATOMIDGETS\bld\Debug" --deployTarget "device"
>   --language en-US --configuration debug
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

4) I suspect it might be due to me updating my NPM and Node. I executed "npm cache clean -f" then used Chocolatey "cinst nodejs.install".

5) If not the forementioned update, the very least suspect that I can point to is me trying to use the Whitelist plugin...which I do not believe to be the cause of this.

6) My device is connected as MTP. It is detected when I type "adb devices".

**Some specifications:**

If this helps, I will list version details.

- Visual Studio 2013 Update 5
- Cordova 6.0.0
- NPM 3.8.1
- Node 5.8.0

I hope someone can kindly direct me as to how to resolve this.
Thank you for the response and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that I did to fix this problem:

1. Cleared the cache once more
2. Reinstalled Cordova
3. Used the latest LTS Node v4.4.0 instead of the latest stable Node 5.8.0. (Which I believe is really the main error fix)

And now I am able to debug on both my emulator and phone. :)

Perhaps the problem was due to mismatched versions?

**Note:** I am still considering explanations. Please feel free to comment or post an answer. Thank you!